AWS Bedrock - Ways to train with my custom data
I wanted to train Bedrock models with my personal data. I have tried several approaches as below

Creating a custom model by providing my personal data in jsonl format
Utilizing AWS bedrock knowledge base to import my data from s3 bucket, creating embeddings in vector db and performing actions through vector search
Utilizing Lambda function, reading my csv file, retrieving the required column and converting into list and prompting bedrocks model to create embeddings from it.
Creating vector db with embeddings for my dataset in AWS open search, then utilizing one of the bedrock's model to prompt it to fetch similar embedding for my input data.

I still want to know if there are any other ways to get results on my personal data through AWS Bedrock. Please suggest me.
